# Maven does not compile classes

Tags: scala, maven

I'm struggling to make maven to compile classes and put them to the `jar`. Searching through the internet I found, that it expects standard structure (like src/java), but it can be overridden by adding

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>correct_path_to_source_files</sourceDirectory>
</build>
```

to `pom.xml`, but it doesn't help, maven keeps ignoring source files without any error: runnning `compile` says `[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`. However, no classes appear in `target/classes` and in `jar` as well. Other than `packaging` and `build` above, `pom` file contains only dependencies.

I'm not a big expert of java/scala, so I have no idea, what does this thing expect from me. Manual build in Idea solves the problem, but shouldn't it be done by assembly system?

How to make maven compile source files?

Comment: The structure is `src/main/java/<package>` for productive code and `src/test/java/<package>` for test code.

Comment: Can you show how does your directory structure looks like. Also, any reason for not using the default structure? Finally, if you are learning **Scala** why not using **sbt** or **mill** instead of **maven**?

Comment: if you have scala classes they should be under `src/main/scala`, and I think you need a maven plugin to compile scala classes